# React style caching issue on mobile browsers

Tags: css, reactjs, heroku, browser, create-react-app

I'm developing a React app with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and deploying to Heroku.

My problem is that every time I push a new update the old browser cached styles get loaded when users go to the app **on mobile devices**... meaning I have to ask my users to repeatedly delete their browser cache.

How can I force the browser to recognize a new CSS file and re-cache (if that's even a thing)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "cache busting". This basically appends a hash to the end of the css filename that changes every time you rebuild. The browser sees this as a new file (because the filename is different) and realizes it doesn't have it cached, so it obtains the resource from your server.

Here is a Webpack plugin you can use. Create React App uses Webpack, so this may be an easy way to accomplish that.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin

Or this may be enabled directly with Webpack:

https://webpack.github.io/docs/long-term-caching.html